# How to send prometheus alert when two expressions pass

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to configure an rule that checks if a mounted partition disappears. I got a challenge when  the host server gets unreachable and false alert is triggered.n

```
absent(node_filesystem_files{job='Server1', instance="hostA:port",mountpoint='/data4'}) == 1
```

The expression above returns `1` when the partition is not present and worked well.

I tried combining the expression above with one checking that the server is `up`. i.e trigger alert when server is reachable and partition missing as below. However, from prometheus docs, the `and` operator seems to do a different operation.

```
absent(node_filesystem_files{job='Server1', instance="hostA:port",mountpoint='/data4'}) == 1
and up{instance="hostA:port", job="Server1"}
```

Comment: Prometheus' `and` does exactly what it says. Your problem is mismatch in labels of RHS and LHS. Read about `on()`